# How to use wildcards in SQL SELECT Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field called Event, it contains data like this:

View:

```
ID Event
1  2015-T4-C 
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-T4-C; 2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C
4  2018-T4-C
5  2015-T4-Z
```

With an SQL SELECT (MSSQL) how can I use wildcards to replace the wildcard portion of a string?

e.g. this is what I am trying to do though does not work. The first occurrence of the replace is to cater for values that have only one instance, the second replace it to cater for values that have multiple instances with a '; ' in them:

```
SELECT
REPLACE(REPLACE(view.Event, '_____T___', ''), '_____T___; ', '')
FROM view
```

The result I am looking for is:

View Result

```
ID Event
1    
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C
4  
5
```

Thank you

Edit: there are multiple instances of 'T's e.g. 2017-T4-C, 2018-T4-C , 2019-T4-C , 2015-T4-Z  so can't use replace on '2015-T4-C'

Edit 2:

p.s.  it starts like this

Original Table

```
ID Event
1  2015-T4-C 
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-T4-C 
3  2015-R4-C
3  2015-Z4-C
etc
```

Then I use a stuff XML query to get them on the same line e.g.

```
3  2015-T4-C; 2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C
```

Edit 3 - Now that I know wildcards are not possible in SELECT replace it changes the question. The result I am looking for is:

```
ID EventFilter1           EventFilter2
1                         2015-T4-C
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C   2015-T4-C
4                         2018-T4-C
5                         2015-T4-Z
```

I can go back to pulling the data from the original table in a different way:

Original Table

```
ID Event
1  2015-T4-C 
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-T4-C 
3  2015-R4-C
3  2015-Z4-C
etc
```

Edit 4: Here is the new question knowing wildcards are not possible:

Hi

I have a table for Customers and I have a Table for Events. There are multiple Events per customer. I need to export into semicolon delimited single line for an external system import splitting the results into two columns depending on a filter.

Events Table:

```
ID Event
1  2015-T4-C 
2  2015-G4-C
3  2015-T4-C 
3  2015-R4-C 
3  2015-Z4-C
4  2018-T4-C 
4  2018-T4-W
4  2018-K4-I
4  2018-Z4-W
5  2015-T4-Z
```

Desired Result:

```
ID EventFilter1(T)       EventFilter2(notT)
1  2015-T4-C
2                        2015-G4-C
3  2015-T4-C             2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C
4  2018-T4-C; 2018-T4-W  2018-K4-I; 2018-Z4-W    
5  2015-T4-Z
```

At the moment I use two separate joins though want to only use one to simply and speed it up. Here is what I do at the moment, how can I simplify this? Goal 1 is to make it faster, Goal 2 is to make it more simple but happy to favor speed over simplicity.

```
SELECT c.ID, e.EventFilter1(T), e2.EventFilter2(notT)
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
           c.ID, 
           EventFilter1(T) = STUFF((
                  SELECT distinct '; ' + e.Event
                  FROM Events e
                  WHERE c.ID = e.ID AND Event like '%-T%'
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
            FROM Customers c WHERE c.ID in (SELECT ID FROM Events)) as e
on c.ID = e.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
           c.ID, 
           EventFilter2(notT) = STUFF((
                  SELECT distinct '; ' + e2.Event
                  FROM Events e2
                  WHERE c.ID = e2.ID AND Event not like '%-T%'
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
            FROM Customers c WHERE c.ID in (SELECT ID FROM Events)) as e2
on c.ID = e2.ID
```

So is there a way I can pull all data without filter in the join sub-query, then filter and split it in the main query or can I pull two sets of data with two filters in one sub query? e.g.:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
       c.ID, 
       EventFilter1(T) = STUFF((
              SELECT distinct '; ' + e.Event
              FROM Events e
              WHERE c.ID = e.ID AND Event like '%-T%'
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
      EventFilter2(notT) = STUFF(( **** What do I put here? ****
        FROM Customers c WHERE c.ID in (SELECT ID FROM Events)) as e
on c.ID = e.ID
```

Comment: You cannot.  An outside observer sees major problems with your database.  Storing lists of things in a delimited string is usually a really bad idea.  And never the SQLish way to store things.

Comment: Any other options? It's ok the data is stored in individual rows in my database. I hear you though, I am importing this data into a system that has the data as a delimited string so have no choice.

Comment: you will have to spill out all the beans bro. there could be a pattern or list to consider

Comment: @SSS . . . You should ask another question and show the data as stored in individual rows.

Comment: Just added some more info @maSTArHiAn

Comment: 2017-T4-C, 2018-T4-C , 2019-T4-C , 2015-T4-Z, 2015-T4-C is this the list?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn there are potentially more. Here is the pattern: AnyYear-T1,T2,T3orT4-ZorC

Comment: sample data for ZorC?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn 4  2018-T4-C and 5  2015-T4-Z

Comment: what are the chances that two or more of these patterns are in 1 row?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn it's possible

Comment: more fun.. the the trimming should be done at the original table and not when it got stuffed.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn another system still needs the original data so can't trim it at original table...

Comment: no we don't we just need to get cleaned result and stuff it. that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY and a little XML as as splitter

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, [Event] varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,  '2015-T4-C'), 
(2,  '2015-G4-C'),
(3,  '2015-T4-C; 2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C'),
(4,  '2018-T4-C'),
(5,  '2015-T4-Z')

Declare @Pattern varchar(100) = '_____T___'

Select A.ID
      ,NewVal =IsNull(B.S,'')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = Stuff((Select '; ' +RetVal 
                  From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[Event],';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
                  Where PatIndex(@Pattern,RetVal)=0
                  Order by RetSeq
                  For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewVal
1   
2   2015-G4-C
3   2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C
4   
5
```

Comment: Thanks this is really close. I already use two stuff xml joins to get the two sets of data though want to do it all in one join. This could work though using the same cross apply how would i then put the removed values into RemovedVal column?

Comment: I have put more details about the new question in my original post. Edit 4.

Comment: @SSS I added a second answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the original problem was incomplete... 
the data we are seeing is a result of a stuff over xml therefore the original table should be cleaned first in order to get the right result.

please find the solution below against tbevents as your original events table.

```
create table #tbpattern(
myPat varchar(10) 
)

insert into #tbpattern
values ('T1'),('T2'),('T3'),('T4-C'),('T4-Z')

select * from #tbpattern


create table #tbevents
(
eventid varchar(1000) 
)


insert into #tbevents 
values ('2015-T4-C'),('2015-G4-C'),('2015-Z4-C'),('2018-T4-C'),('2015-T4-Z')


select e.eventid
from #tbevents e
where not exists
(
select 1 from #tbpattern p where charindex(p.myPat,e.eventid) > 0
)



drop table #tbpattern
drop table #tbevents
```

> apply STUFF from the result above

Comment: Thanks though I should mention there are multiple instances of 'T's e.g. 2017-T4-C, 2018-T4-C , 2019-T4-C , 2015-T4-Z

Comment: then you just have to explicitly add them to the text or have a compounded replace statement or a pattern

Comment: it could go either way... have a definite list of keywords or have a pattern

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed length strings.  This does give you some options.  Here is one rather painful one:

```
select (case when substr(t.event, 6, 1) = 'T'
             then stuff(t.event, 1, 11, '')
             when substr(t.event, 17, 1) = 'T'
             then stuff(t.event, 12, 11, '')
             when substr(t.event, 28, 1) = 'T'
             then stuff(t.event, 23, 11, '')
             . . .
         end)
```

This does have the downside of removing only one.

Answer (score 0):

I added another answer because the EDITS a departure from the original question

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, [Event] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1  ,'2015-T4-C'), 
(2  ,'2015-G4-C'),
(3  ,'2015-T4-C'),
(3  ,'2015-R4-C'),
(3  ,'2015-Z4-C'),
(4  ,'2018-T4-C'), 
(4  ,'2018-T4-W'),
(4  ,'2018-K4-I'),
(4  ,'2018-Z4-W'),
(5  ,'2015-T4-Z')

Declare @Pattern varchar(100) = '_____T___' 

Select A.ID
      ,NewCol1 = IsNull(B.S,'')
      ,NewCol2 = IsNull(C.S,'')
 From  (Select Distinct ID from @YourTable) A
 Cross Apply (
               Select S = Stuff((Select Distinct '; ' +[Event] 
                 From @YourTable
                 Where PatIndex(@Pattern,[Event])=0
                    and ID = A.ID
                 For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
               Select S = Stuff((Select Distinct '; ' +[Event] 
                 From @YourTable
                 Where PatIndex(@Pattern,[Event])>0
                    and ID = A.ID
                 For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewCol1                 NewCol2
1                           2015-T4-C
2   2015-G4-C   
3   2015-R4-C; 2015-Z4-C    2015-T4-C
4   2018-K4-I; 2018-Z4-W    2018-T4-C; 2018-T4-W
5                           2015-T4-Z
```